# “No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath” when I adapt quarkus to a simple spring boot project？

Tags: java, quarkus

I try to use quarkus in my simple spring boot project recently. However, when I execute "mvn compile quarkus:dev", the spring WebapplicationInitializer types cannot cannot be detected.

Although I know quarkus does not support spring boot in some ways, I want to figure out why it happens?

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.version>0.18.0</quarkus.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
           <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
           <artifactId>quarkus-spring-di</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>native-image</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
         <native.image.path>
            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
         </native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And this is the result/log.

```
2019-07-16 15:27:17,757 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Beginning quarkus augmentation
2019-07-16 15:27:19,054 INFO  [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanProcessor] (build-13) -13) 
Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
     - @Inject field com.example.demo.GreeterBean#messageProducer
2019-07-16 15:27:19,325 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) ain) 
Quarkus augmentation completed in 1568ms
2019-07-16 15:27:19,831 INFO  [io.und.servlet] (main) No Spring
 WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2019-07-16 15:27:20,177 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus rkus 
0.18.0 started in 2.698s. Listening on: http://[::]:8080
2019-07-16 15:27:20,178 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installetalle
d features: [cdi, resteasy, spring-di]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you shouldn't use Quarkus together with Spring Boot.

They are different frameworks with different approaches: it's either one or the other.

What's missing in Quarkus that you want to use Spring Boot too?

Comment: Thanks.  I have a spring boot project and I try to combine it with quarkus. Now I know it does not work, but I still want to figure out why is that "spring WebapplicationInitializer types cannot cannot be detected"?   Besides, is it true that Quarkus does not support Spring AOP yet?  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Hello, I think I have made a mistake,. Spring WebApplicationInitializer is not the cause of my problem. Anyway, thanks!